# $f$ is integrable $\iff \sum_{k=-\infty }^\infty 2^k m(F_k)$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f\geq 0$ measurable and finite a.e. Let $$F_k=\{x\mid 2^k< f(x)\leq 2^{k+1}\},$$
and thus $$\{x\mid f(x)>0\}=\bigcup_{k=-\infty }^\infty  F_k$$
where the union is disjoint. Show that $f$ is integrable $\iff \sum_{k=-\infty }^\infty  2^k m(F_k)<\infty $.

**Solution**

We have that $2^k<f\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{F_k}\leq 2^{k+1}$ and thus
$$\sum_{k=-\infty }^\infty 2^k\boldsymbol 1_{F_k}\leq f\leq \sum_{k=-\infty }^\infty 2^{k+1}\boldsymbol 1_{F_k}.$$

**Q1) I don't understand this implication. Shouldn't it be
$\sum_{k=-\infty }^\infty 2^k\leq f\leq \sum_{k=-\infty }^\infty 2^{k+1}$ ?**

**Q2) How can I introduce $\sum_{k=-\infty }^\infty 2^k\boldsymbol 1_{F_k}$ form here ?**

Comment: Perhaps the inequality should be $2^k\cdot \mathbf{1}_{F_k} \leq f \cdot \mathbf{1}_{F_k} \leq 2^{k + 1}\mathbf{1}_{F_k}$.